# How to measure biosignals with 1800's technology?

Tags: operational-amplifier

Say, you are in a 1800's(all of 1800s) setting where you only have inductors capacitors and resistors and you are trying to detect a signal coming from a persons body. How would you design them?

If you already couldn't tell this is a discussion that I am having with peers in my bio instrumentation class. I am just baffled on what to do. How the heck would you mimic an opamp only using 1800s technologies (e.g capacitors resistors and inductors) Picture for the description is shown below. How in the world would you "amplify" signals from the heart without an opamp?

Comment: Machinery is how. You have amplification through levers or horn shapes, for example. Filtering through dashpots, springs, etc. It would cost a lot, today. It would require maintenance, repair, lubrication, and replacements. But there's nothing new in the world about signals, feedback, and amplification. But much good theory has occurred and mathematics has grown. So you could do more, and do it more quickly, applying today's knowledge brought back, I think.

Comment: The stethoscope was invented in France in 1816 by René Laennec. It consisted of a wooden tube; remember that with a cone of paper you can ear things that normally you cant, On that time elder people used to use  a sheep horn to hear .

Comment: According to Wikipedia article on [Electrocardiography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrocardiography), there were ECG machines in that era (late 1800's, early 1900's) using [Lippmann Electrometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lippmann_electrometer) or the more sensitive [String Galvanometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_galvanometer) as the sensor.

Comment: Galvani recorded electrical activity in frog muscle in the late 1700's

Comment: Read this paper:  Majd AlGhatrif MD & Joseph Lindsay MD (2012) A brief review: history to
understand fundamentals of electrocardiography, Journal of Community Hospital Internal Medicine
Perspectives, 2:1, 14383  Filtering is not really much of an issue with pre-1900 technology, it's correcting for the inherent low-pass filtering of the primitive devices that can (barely) be produced.

Comment: Questions should be searchable and indexable by a search engine. You need to transcribe the text and not just paste it as an image.

Answer (score 2):

You would not use any electronic amplifier at all, because you simply were not able to build one without tubes (which only arrived at marked after 1900) or semiconductors.

What people actually did back then was to design mechenical devices, to show a visible signal amplitude. I guess the most significant one was the already by MarkU mentioned String Galvanometer. It used a very lightweight and thereby sensitive wire, which was deflectet in the elcetrical field of the signal. To make this little movement visible without influencing the signal itself (or decreasing the amplitude due to some load) the amplification was done optically by projecting the wire on the wall.

Regarding your direct tasks: These questions do not aim an the design of an "opamp" but on filter circuits and electrodes. You can use the named passiv components to build filtering circuits to remove noise components of your signal. First of all you would want a low pass filtering. The electric signal from the heart does not contain any information in the frequency range over 100 Hz - so you can reduce noise a lot by limiting this upper frequency. Additionaly the respiration will distorte the baseline of you signal with a frequency below 1 Hz - so you want to also block these low frequencies. This can be done by resistors, capacitors and inductors.

The electrodes are another topic: You can not simply use metal wire to connect to peoples skin to your apparatus, because you have a transition from electron conduction in the metal to ion conduction in biological tissue. A simple metal electrode will polarize and increase in resistance a lot. Therefore you use electrodes, which are designed for this transistion and which can deliver the needed ions. A reasonable example would be silver/silver chloride electrodes, although back in 1800 I guess you would just put the extremities in large metal buckets of saltwater.

Answer (score 1):

Galvani demonstrated that frog muscle contraction was produced by electricity in the late 1700's.  While he used Leyden jars to cause contraction, he is credited with using the frog leg prep to actually indicate the presence of electricity:  the [frog galvanoscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frog_galvanoscope)

Traditional Galvanometers have been around since the early 1800's, when it was demonstrated that compass needles move around small currents.  Galvanometers could measure microamps.

The 1840's brought us the Kymograph -- essentially a rotating smoked drum.  A galvanometer needle could be used to scratch out patterns in the smoke particles on the drum.